# Automatically forward google play crash reports to developer email address

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

My client has restricted access to their google play developer console and they only send me crash reports every month or so. They also restrict the number of third party plugins used in their app so I cannot add Bugsense or Crashalytics. Does anyone know if its possible to setup a daily automatic forwarding of crash and ANR reports from the google play developer console to a third party email address?

Comment: I'm also interested in this.